# Hide options in a select list using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, database

How can I hide room numbers that is not at Hotel1 and send chosen room number to next page when you click on submit button. As it is now I will be forced to send only the id for chosen hotel because i need to have the value for selHotel options and selroom the same.

I'm using php, html and Sqlite database. hotelrows and roomrows contains all rows of hotel table and rooms table. Can anyone give me an idea of ​​how I could get this to work? Ie when choosing Hotel1 I can just choose room 101 or 102 in selroom for example. (Sorry if my English is bad, hopefully someone understands what I'm asking for.)

```
Hotels:
id.....Hotel
1......Hotel1
2......Hotel2

Rooms:
hid....Room#
1.......101
1.......102
2.......301
```

My php/html:

```
<select id="selHotel" name="selH">
<option value="default" selected> Select hotel</option>
<?php
  foreach($hotelrows as $row)
  {
    echo "<option value='". $row['id'] . "'>". $row['hotelname'] . "</option>";
  }
?>
 </select>

 <select id="selroom" name="selr">
<option value="default" selected>Select room </option>
<?php
  foreach($roomrows as $row)
  {
    echo "<option value='". $row['hid'] . "'>". $row['roomnum'] . "</option>";
      }
?>
 </select>
```

jQuery to hide Hotel2 Rooms then i choose Hotel1:

```
$("#selHotel").change(function(){
        var hotelVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        $('#selroom option').hide();
        $('#selroom option[value='+hotelVal+']').show();
    });
```

Comment: The main idea of your code looks sound. What isn't working?

Comment: On the page insert.php it works. It is, however, when I click submit and use POST to send this to other.php. Then, $ row ['hid']need to be $ row ['roomnum'] so I can use the room number i chose at insert.php.

id and hid are connected in the database and are the same number, the id of the hotel in hotel table. So in other.php I only get the value of id and hid when i do this: $_POST['selr']. That is because i set the value of the option af the id. The problem is how can i filter out the room numbers and be able to send the number i choose as value for the select box?

Answer (score 0):

Use the roomnum as value, add your hid as class, then use it as filter when selected:

php:

```
echo "<option class='cls_". $row['hid'] . "' vlaue='".$row['roomnum']."'>". $row['roomnum'] . "</option>";
```

page

```
$("#selHotel").change(function(){
    var hotelVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $('#selroom option').hide();
    $('#selroom .cls_'+hotelVal).show();
    $('#selroom .cls_'+hotelVal).first().attr('selected',true);
});
```